# unix - how to get (2) columns from each dictionary, from a list of dictionaries

Tags: list, unix, dictionary, data-structures

-I'm new to programming

-How would I get 2 specific columns from a list of dictionaries in Unix?

-Example code... just 2 of the dicts in the list

```
[{"prescSpecialty": "10201", "threeDigitSubsZip": "852", "untsDispensedQuantity": "60.000", "generic": "Y", "gender": "F", "ndc": "0378-3125-01", "dispenseQuarter": "2011Q3", "ndc11Digit": "00378312501", "birthYear": "1951", "threeDigitPhmZip": " ", "daysSupplyCount": "30", "newRefillCount": "2"}, {"prescSpecialty": "10201", "threeDigitSubsZip": "199", "untsDispensedQuantity": "30.000", "generic": "N", "gender": "F", "ndc": "0002-4771-90", "dispenseQuarter": "2011Q3", "ndc11Digit": "00002477190", "birthYear": "1950", "threeDigitPhmZip": " ", "daysSupplyCount": "30", "newRefillCount": "0"}]
```

-I tried using cut but it doesn't have to be a cut based solution,

```
cut -f 4,6 -d, claims.json
```

-it only gave me the first dictionary in the list

```
"generic": "Y", "ndc": "0378-3125-01"
```

-i'd like the expected output to be two columns of just the 'generic' and "ndc" values

-I want to do this in Unix before putting this in Pandas

-Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ok great I'll try editing it. I added a link to the file through my GitHub account. https://github.com/dav1dfeldman/DAT_SF_11/blob/master/labs/lab_01/claims.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/ {/\n/g' yourJsonFile | cut -d, -f4,6
```

---

@shelter found the answer, I do't know why he deleted it. It just missed the space before the `{` character to avoid `sed` to put a `\n` in the first ocurrence of `{` creating a line consisting by just a `[`.

#### Example

```
$ cat yourJsonFile
[{"prescSpecialty": "10201", "threeDigitSubsZip": "852", "untsDispensedQuantity": "60.000", "generic": "Y", "gender": "F", "ndc": "0378-3125-01", "dispenseQuarter": "2011Q3", "ndc11Digit": "00378312501", "birthYear": "1951", "threeDigitPhmZip": " ", "daysSupplyCount": "30", "newRefillCount": "2"}, {"prescSpecialty": "10201", "threeDigitSubsZip": "199", "untsDispensedQuantity": "30.000", "generic": "N", "gender": "F", "ndc": "0002-4771-90", "dispenseQuarter": "2011Q3", "ndc11Digit": "00002477190", "birthYear": "1950", "threeDigitPhmZip": " ", "daysSupplyCount": "30", "newRefillCount": "0"}]

$ sed 's/ {/\n/g' yourJsonFile | cut -d, -f4,6
 "generic": "Y", "ndc": "0378-3125-01"
 "generic": "N", "ndc": "0002-4771-90"
```

Comment: Glad you got it. I didn't have time to tidy up. Good luck to all!